# Regex: Find words that have a O in second position AND end in IONS

Tags: python, regex

The other day, I was trying to teach the principles of Regex to a student - I am far from an expert but wanted to show the principles of it. I have a text file containing all the words of the English language, and I wanted to define a series of rules in regex so that the only word that would come out would be "CONGRATULATIONS".

We did it in Python code first, then using the re python library. The two first rules were to find words having O as the second letter, and words ending in IONS.

While we first tried to find the words matching a rule and then the other in pure Python, we tried to do it in one go using the regex pattern `^.O[A-Z]*IONS$`. We were surprised to see that the two methods differed by one word: **IONS**.

I mean, it totally makes sense, as the regex pattern is looking, by definition, for words of at least 6 characters. But it got us wondering if there was a way to get the words that have O as a second letter, which can also be the O of IONS in one single regex pattern.

I know we can totally do it in two steps, first getting the words having an O as the second letter, and then getting the words ending in IONS among these words, but I just wondered if it was possible in one step alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is:

```
^([A-Z]O[A-Z]*)?IONS$
```

Explanation:

Using Venn diagram.

- Rule 1: words with O as second letter `^.O` or `^.O.*$
- Rule 2: words that ends with IONS `IONS$` or `^.*IONS$

In the intersection of Rule 1 & 2 (there are  *<strike>3</strike>*  **2** disjoint cases):

- **case 1** the shortest word is the word IONS,
- None for 5 letters, second letters are contradicting: "O" in *rule 1* while "I" in *rule 2*
- **case 2** for 6 letters and above: your pattern suffices.

union of these  *<strike>3</strike>*  **2** is `IONS` OR your pattern

which is `^(IONS|.O.*IONS)$` or `^(IONS|.O.*IONS)$`

but *as @InSync commented* you can simplify it to

```
^(.O.*)?IONS$
```

how & why? since:

- *A:* the word IONS satisfies both rules, **satisfying one would would match IONS.** Let's keep the stricter *rule 2*. `IONS$`

  - 4-letter word: `^IONS$`
- *B:* there are **2 cases.** We can make rule 1 optional *(rule1)?*, when matching:

  - 6-letter words`^(.O)?IONS$` or
  - 6+letter words `^(.O.*)?IONS$`

or even stricter as needed: if 'words' is A-Z only

```
^([A-Z]O[A-Z]*)?IONS$
```

Comment: A more idiomatic way to write this pattern is to make the first part optional: `^(.O.*)?IONS$`.

Comment: Nice catch @InSync , that matches a word with 4 or 6+ letters.

Comment: I tend to agree with @InSync, but your answer is arguably easier for readers to understand. Incidentally, whenever I see a capture group being used in a regex I  am expecting its contents will be back-referenced later in the regex or extracted for use later in the code. While that only cost me 11 grey-matter cycles here, I suggest that as a rule you avoid using a capture group when a non-capture group will due (assuming the language--Python being one--supports non-capture groups).

Answer (score 1):

You can use look-ahead group ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SmC8J8/1)):

```
^(?=.O).*IONS$
```

---

- `^` - start of the line
- `(?=.O)` - positive lookahead (match any character and then `O`)
- `.*IONS$` - match any number of characters + `IONS` + end of the line

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your attempt is that you are saying any character, followed by O, followed by zero or more characters, followed by IONS, followed by end of line. I think you can see from this exposition why it will not match the word IONS; it does not contain O followed by IONS.

A lookahead is one way to do it, but what exactly to put in the lookahead can be varied.

- `^(?=.O).*IONS$*` moves the requirement on the second character into a lookahead, but then says "any string which ends with IONS" as the actual thing to match.
- `^.O.*(?<=IONS)$` moves the IONS requirement to a lookbehind. I'm sure you can now also see how to change this to move the condition for the beginning of the string into a lookahead if you like.
- `^(?=.*IONS$)(?=.O).*` matches a line which matches two lookaheads. Neither of those consume the entire string, so the actual match is then "any string" (we have no additional requirements on the match).

In so many words, a lookaround (lookahead or lookbehind) specifies an additional requirement which can exclude some matches. Similarly to how `^` doesn't really match any text, but says "you must be looking at the beginning of line", a lookaround says "at this point, you need to be looking at ... this" (looking ahead, at the text immediately after the current point in the text being matched, or behind, on text you already matched, immediately before the current point in the text).

These all assume you are operating on a word list containing one word per line. You can modify the beginning and end of string anchors (`^` and `$`) to word boundaries (`\b`) to work on arbitrary text; but then you will also change the `.` occurrences to `\w` or perhaps `\S` to make sure it matches only word characters or non-whitespace character, respectively.